# recursive function does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone explain the code? I just can not understand why this code gives output like this:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

I expected the code to give something like this:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
```

What am I missing here?

```py
def tri_recursion(k):
    if(k > 0):
        result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result

tri_recursion(6)
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the output `1 3 5 7 9 11` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your recursive function, the termination condition is `k=0`.

It's clear that if k=0, tri_recursion(0) = 0.

If `k=1`, tri_recursion(1) = 1 + tri_recursion(0), which from above, is `1 + 0` or `1`.
If `k=2`, tri_recursion(2) = 2 + tri_recursion(1), which from above, is `2 + 1` or `3`.
If `k=3`, tri_recursion(3) = 3 + tri_recursion(2), which from above, is `3 + 3` or `6`.
If `k=4`, tri_recursion(4) = 5 + tri_recursion(3), which from above, is `4 + 6` or `10`.
If `k=5`, tri_recursion(5) = 4 + tri_recursion(4), which from above, is `5 + 10` or `15`.
If `k=6`, tri_recursion(6) = 6 + tri_recursion(5), which from above, is `6 + 15` or `21`.

See the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is calculating the sum of numbers up to `n` where n is `6` in the above case. The `print` statement prints the intermediate results. Hence the output `1 3 6 10 15 21`.

1 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 1

3 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 2

6 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 3

10 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 4

15 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 5

21 - The sum of numbers from 0 to 6

Comment: How should I understand this portion of code  result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)